# C# AES-128 CFB Error

Tags: c#, aes

I currently set up RijndaelManaged this way (the IV and Key are the same due to how the server handles the encryption). The server also uses CFB8 for the Mode, did I set this up correctly?

```
    public static RijndaelManaged GenerateAES(byte[] key)
    {
        RijndaelManaged cipher = new RijndaelManaged();
        cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
        cipher.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        cipher.KeySize = 128;
        cipher.Key = key;
        cipher.IV = key;

        return cipher;
    }
```

I write data by doing this:
            ICryptoTransform e = GenerateAES(key).CreateEncryptor();

```
        using(CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(BaseStream, e, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            stream.WriteByte(b);
            stream.FlushFinalBlock();
        }
```

BaseStream is a NetworkStream that I opened, and 'b' is a value that I sent to my function.

When I try to a 0x00 (as a test) to the stream, I get this error:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Length of the data to encrypt is invalid.
at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.EncryptData(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount, Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32 outputOffset, PaddingMode paddingMode, Boolean fLast)
at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.IO.Stream.Close()
```

I only made this function test whether or not that if I can communicate to the server without relying on any external libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've set the `PaddingMode` to None, and are trying to encrypt fewer bytes than a full block of data. Either encrypt more data (a multiple of the `cipher.BlockSize`) or set the padding mode to something other than None so that it's automatically padded to the appropriate length.

**Edit:**

The default FeedbackSize for RijndaelManaged is 128 bits, but you want to use CFB8. If you set the `cipher.FeedbackSize` to 8, you will be able to use it as a stream cipher with no padding, and every byte written to the CryptoStream will be encrypted and written to the output stream immediately. You should *not* call `FlushFinalBlock` after each write, as this terminates the encryption process.

Comment: The padding is none, I am sure of that. Out of desperation I tried changing the PaddingMode to Zeroes, *it seemed* to work, until I got write errors (the stream suddenly became not able to write).

Comment: @SwDevMan81 No, padding is applied to the plaintext prior to encryption to permit block ciphers (like AES) to operate on plaintext of any length. From MSDN on the PaddingMode enumeration: "Most plain text messages do not consist of a number of bytes that completely fill blocks. Often, there are not enough bytes to fill the last block. When this happens, a padding string is added to the text."

Comment: @0xFF If the server uses no padding, then the data you are encrypting *must* be of a length equal to a multiple of the block size, that's simply how block ciphers work.

Comment: +1 Sounds good to me - Just change your test data to be 128 bits (default blocksize) and it should work.

Comment: The problem is I will need to write a byte or a byte array (array of any length) at any time, how can I avoid a problem like this in the future?

Comment: @0xFF That's fine, you can write arbitrary amounts of data at a time, but when you call FlushFinalBlock, the total amount of data written must be a multiple of the block size. You should only be calling FlushFinalBlock when you are finished writing *all* of the data to the CryptoStream.

Comment: The thing is, this is a continuous stream, I've read up on the CFB mode, and does it not need the previous blocks to encrypt/decrypt the future data? If not, can I just call FlushFinalBlock() after I wrote the data I needed?

Comment: @0xFF Having looked into this further, it seems that the critical thing that's been missed here is setting the Feedback size to 8 (making it CFB8 as required). Once this is done, you can encrypt a single byte at a time with no padding, and should *not* call FlushFinalBlock. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! To anyone else, AVOID USING A CRYTOSTREAM, instead use the ICryptoTransform.TransformBlock() method!

Comment: The CryptoStream disposes itself after a write, that includes the previous stream, bewarned!

Comment: @0xFF Assuming you are still using the above code or something similar, the CryptoStream only disposed itself because it's in a using block, which will dispose the stream (and presumably the wrapped stream too) when the block is completed. You should only be disposing the stream when you are completely finished using it.

Answer (score 0):

Provided a solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29038974/725903

The idea is to wrap ICryptoTransform passed to a CryptoStream ctor that handles TransformFinalBlock adding required bytes before encryption/decryption and removing them on return