# C# aes encryption: Input size not output size

Tags: c#, sockets, encryption, aes

I'm trying to read a file, encrypt it, and send it to a server over socket, where it is written. And then the other way around, read it on server, send it to client, decrypt it, and write it again.

My problem using C# Aes class is, that the input size doesn't equal the output size.

For example, when I read 4096 bytes from the file, the output size is 4112 bytes, 16 bytes more. OK, so 4112 bytes are sent and written on the server, but when I get the file again, I can only send a maximum of 4096 bytes over the socket, and then, of course, the decrypt function on client throws an exception, that the padding is invalid and cannot be removed. Sure I could try to read less bytes on the client, but that doesn't work as well.

I'm a very experienced C++ programmer, and I've done this with OpenSsl, and it worked like a charm. The input size has been always the output size, I don't know what is wrong with my functions in C#.

this is the sending part:

```
byte[]  SendData = new byte[4096];

iBytesRead = FileRead.Read (SendData, 0, 4096);

SendData = aes.encrypt (Encoding.Default.GetString (SendData, 0, iBytesRead), iBytesRead);

String a = aes.decrypt (SendData); // no problems here because the size is correct

Socket.sendB     (SendData, SendData.Length);
```

and the part of receiving from server:

```
byte[] WriteData = new byte[4096],
                   Temp;

if ((iBytesReceived = Socket.receiveB (ref WriteData)) == 0)
    break;

if (Encoding.ASCII.GetString (WriteData, 0, iBytesReceived) == "end")
    break;


for (uint i = 0; i < iBytesReceived; i++)
    Temp[i] = WriteData[i];

byte[] a = Encoding.Default.GetBytes (aes.decrypt (Temp));

FileWrite.Write (a, 0, Temp.Length);
```

Aes functions:

```
public byte[] encrypt(String _InStr, int _InStrLength)
    {
        if (!bKeySet)
            return ErrorReturn;

        byte[] encrypted;

        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create ())
        {
            aes.Key = Key;
            aes.IV = IV;

            //aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            //aes.BlockSize = 128;
            //aes.KeySize = 128;
            //aes.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption. 
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
                    {
                        sw.Write(_InStr);                   
                    }
                }

                ms.Close ();

                encrypted = ms.ToArray (); 
            }
        }

        return encrypted;
    }

    public String decrypt(byte[] _InStr)
    {
        if (!bKeySet)
            return "";

        String plaintext;


        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create ())
        {
            aes.Key = Key;
            aes.IV = IV;

            //aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            //aes.BlockSize = 128;
            //aes.KeySize = 128;
            //aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption. 
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(_InStr))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd ();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return plaintext;
    }
```

Comment: The input size can only equal the output size when you use NoPadding. PKCS7Padding always produces 1-16 additional bytes (for AES) to fill up to a multiple of 16. So you might try to read 4095 bytes instead of 4096. It's not clear why you can't use a smaller buffer.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Then I get this in the encryption function: `The input data is not a complete block`

Answer (score 0):

As it was said, if any padding is used, the output will be aligned to a block size. However .Net doesn't want to work with incomplete blocks when PaddingMode.None is used. You should pad data yourself before encryption(decryption) and remove added bytes after.
One of the way to do this is to [wrap ICryptoTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29038974/725903) passed to a CryptoStream