# Cryptographic code in CSharp similar to code in Go (AES,CFB,XorKeyStream)

Tags: c#, go, cryptography, aes

I have cryptographic code in Go but I can't hard find similar code in CSharp.
I am debating to make my own implementation of XorKeyStream but I am told that there is legal issue if I write my own cryptographic code. I am sure there must be similar code in CSharp.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    k1 := []byte("0123456789abcdef")
    r1 := []byte("1234567890abcdef")
    data := []byte("0123456789")
    fmt.Printf("original %x %s\n", data, string(data))

    {
        block, _ := aes.NewCipher(k1)
        stream := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, r1)
        stream.XORKeyStream(data, data)
        fmt.Printf("crypted %x\n", data)
    }
    {
        block, _ := aes.NewCipher(k1)
        stream := cipher.NewCFBDecrypter(block, r1)
        stream.XORKeyStream(data, data)
        fmt.Printf("decrypted %x %s\n", data, string(data))
    }

}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/EnJ56dYX_-

**output**

```
original 30313233343536373839 0123456789
crypted 762b6dcea9c2a7460db7
decrypted 30313233343536373839 0123456789
```

**PS**
Some people marked that question as possible duplicate of question: "C# AES: Encrypt a file causes “Length of the data to encrypt is invalid.” error" 
I look for identical code in CSharp for existing code in Go. That question is about padding. This algorithm needs "Key stream" that will xor text. 
It is different questions.

Comment: Is it even legal to calling Xor "cryptography".:)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well, it depends on how the XOR is applied, RC4 is cryptography and it does a xor...

Comment: aes/cfb creates encrypt stream that is xored with text and result is encrypted text. It is encryption. Nothing wrong with xor here. I can't find something like XORKeyStream in .NET

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# AES: Encrypt a file causes "Length of the data to encrypt is invalid." error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641957/c-sharp-aes-encrypt-a-file-causes-length-of-the-data-to-encrypt-is-invalid-e)

Comment: A mode of operation like CFB converts a block cipher like AES to a stream cipher. A stream cipher creates a *key stream* that is then XORed with the plaintext. `XorKeyStream` is nothing more than the actual encryption.

Comment: Interestingly in this case, both CTR and CFB modes produce the same encrypted data.

Comment: The use of cryptographic libraries should not be considered "writing your own cryptographic code", especially if the protocol is already set. Now inventing your own protocol is, and just applying a cipher may not be secure enough for transport mode encryption. What are you expecting us to do here, do the work for you? What have you tried and where did it go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your code

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

class AES_CFB_XorKeyStream
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0123456789");
        byte [] k1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0123456789abcdef");
        byte [] r1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1234567890abcdef");

        Console.WriteLine("original " + BitConverter.ToString(data));

        using (RijndaelManaged Aes128 = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            Aes128.BlockSize = 128;
            Aes128.KeySize = 128;
            Aes128.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
            Aes128.FeedbackSize = 128;
            Aes128.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            Aes128.Key = k1;
            Aes128.IV = r1;

            using (var encryptor = Aes128.CreateEncryptor())
            using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(csEncrypt, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                bw.Write(data);
                bw.Close();

                data = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                Console.WriteLine("crypted " + BitConverter.ToString(data));
            }
        }

        using (RijndaelManaged Aes128 = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            Aes128.BlockSize = 128;
            Aes128.KeySize = 128;
            Aes128.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
            Aes128.FeedbackSize = 128;
            Aes128.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            Aes128.Key = k1;
            Aes128.IV = r1;

            using (var decryptor = Aes128.CreateDecryptor())
            using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(csEncrypt, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                bw.Write(data);
                bw.Close();

                data = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                Console.WriteLine("decrypted " + BitConverter.ToString(data));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
original 30-31-32-33-34-35-36-37-38-39
crypted 76-2B-6D-CE-A9-C2-A7-46-0D-B7
decrypted 30-31-32-33-34-35-36-37-38-39
```

Comment: I get this exception: `Run-time exception (line 32): Length of the data to encrypt is invalid.`. If I change `FeedbackSize = 8`, the error no longer occurs, but the encrypted data differs after the first byte per block. This means data encrypted with Go is not properly decrypted in C# (only the first byte is correct). Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same issue with only the first byte of each decrypted block being correct, but I did not have the luxury of being able to change source on the Go program.

I ended up implementing my own padding. Just pad the encrypted bytes with 0 bytes to make it divisible by the block size of 128, then after running through the decryption routine, chop that number of bytes off the end.

Example code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Linq;

public static class Program
{
    static RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged(){
        Mode = CipherMode.CFB,
        BlockSize = 128,
        KeySize = 128,
        FeedbackSize = 128,
        Padding = PaddingMode.None
    };

    public static void Main(){
        byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0123456789abcdef");
        byte[] iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1234567890abcdef");
        byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[]{0x76, 0x2b, 0x6d, 0xce, 0xa9, 0xc2, 0xa7, 0x46, 0x0d, 0xb7};

        // Custom pad the bytes
        int padded;
        encryptedBytes = PadBytes(encryptedBytes, aes.BlockSize, out padded);

        // Decrypt bytes
        byte[] decryptedBytes = DecryptBytesAES(encryptedBytes, key, iv, encryptedBytes.Length);

        // Check for successful decrypt
        if(decryptedBytes != null){
            // Unpad
            decryptedBytes = UnpadBytes(decryptedBytes, padded);
            Console.Write("Decrypted: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes));
        }

    }

    // Just an elegant way of initializing an array with bytes
    public static byte[] Initialize(this byte[] array, byte value, int length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = value;
        }
        return array;
    }

    // Custom padding to get around the issue of how Go uses CFB mode without padding differently than C#
    public static byte[] PadBytes(byte[] encryptedBytes, int blockSize, out int numPadded)
    {
        numPadded = 0;

        // Check modulus of block size
        int mod = encryptedBytes.Length % blockSize;
        if (mod != 0)
        {
            // Calculate number to pad
            numPadded = blockSize - mod;

            // Build array
            return encryptedBytes.Concat(new byte[numPadded].Initialize(0, numPadded)).ToArray();
        }
        else {
            // No padding needed
            return encryptedBytes;
        }
    }
    public static byte[] UnpadBytes(byte[] decryptedBytes, int numPadded)
    {
        if(numPadded != 0)
        {
            byte[] unpaddedBytes = new byte[decryptedBytes.Length - numPadded];
            Array.Copy(decryptedBytes, unpaddedBytes, unpaddedBytes.Length);
            return unpaddedBytes;
        }
        else
        {
            return decryptedBytes;
        }
    }

    public static byte[] DecryptBytesAES(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV, int size)
    {
        byte[] array = new byte[size];
        try{
            aes.Key = Key;
            aes.IV = IV;
            ICryptoTransform transform = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Read(array, 0, size);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

.NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NPHKN3

Comment: Looking back at this years later, it may be more efficient to implement something like PKCS#7 padding instead - then you don't have to really store the number of padded bytes at all.