# Problems with Padding.None in RijndaelManaged in CFB mode

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I've already searched on the internet and on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find a solution to the following question:

I want to encrypt and decrypt data with AES algorithm in CFB mode. As far as I've read, CFB mode doesn't require padding and the encrypted data has the same size as the unencrypted data. However, when I set Padding to None and keep the standard Feedback Size at 128 bits, I get an exception saying that the length of the data to write/encrypt is invalid.

When I change the Feedback Size to 8 bits, everything works fine. But this is an extremly inefficent and therefore slow encryption process. As far as I understood, CFB can use standard Feedback Size and handle data that is shorter than the full length of a block.

Init-Code:

```
RijndaelManaged aes_algorithm = new RijndaelManaged();
ICryptoTransform crypto_transform;
CryptoStream crypto_stream;

aes_algorithm.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
aes_algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
aes_algorithm.FeedbackSize = 128;
aes_algorithm.KeySize = aes_key.Length * 8;
aes_algorithm.BlockSize = aes_iv.Length * 8;
crypto_transform = aes_algorithm.CreateEncryptor(aes_key, aes_iv);
```

Encryption

```
MemoryStream Memory = new MemoryStream();
crypto_stream = new CryptoStream(Memory, crypto_transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
crypto_stream.Write(Input, 0, Input.Length);
crypto_stream.FlushFinalBlock();
crypto_stream.Dispose();
crypto_transform.Dispose();
byte[] Output = Memory.ToArray();
Memory.Dispose();
```

So what am I doing wrong or is that a bug in .NET? I've just found this topic [C# AES-128 CFB Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776227/c-sharp-aes-128-cfb-error), but there was also no real solution, except for the manual shortening of the encrypted data (which is not a nice solution, but merely a workaround).

Comment: CFB mode encrypts `FeedbackSize` bits every time, if you set it to 128, it certainly requires padding. But can't get it work even using `FeedbackSize = 8`, could you please tell me how did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

CFB mode is usually implemented as CFB-8, that is, it encrypts 8 bits at a time.

See Wikipedia: [Cipher feedback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher_feedback_.28CFB.29)